# Как вырезать результат списка

Tags: python, строки, list

Дан результат получения списка списков - я написал вот такой код:

```
def check_elemnts_list():
    for i in my_list():
        print(i.split(' ')[-1:])
```

Получаю вот такой результат

```
['"remerplumbing-com.relay1g.spamh.com"]]']
['[]']
['"psd1-org.mail.protection.outlook.com"]]']
['"avionte-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"]]']
['"lastmx.spamexperts.net"]]']
['"mx30.mailspamprotection.com"]]']
['"grupocarval-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"]]']
['"planttape-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"]]']
['"alt3.aspmx.l.google.com"]]']
['"mx30.mailspamprotection.com"]]']
['[]']
['"mail2.qlc.co.in"]]']
['"mail.aherhn.org"]]']
['"aureon-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"]]']
['"thomascookairlines-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"]]']
['"yourcourts-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"]]']
```

[image: но в нем содержаться строки и я хочу вырезать только]

То есть, мне нужно получить вот такой результат:

```
outlook.com
outlook.com
pphosted.com
arsmtp.com
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Comment: а что у вас до вашего сплита? и что делать с доменами типа `qlc.co.in`?

Comment: https://imgur.com/btgHSjQ до сплита у меня вот такой результат

Answer (score 6):

Есть неплохая библиотека получения домена [tld](https://github.com/barseghyanartur/tld). Ее можно применить для парсинга url.

```
import re
from tld import get_fld

hosts_list = [['"remerplumbing-com.relay1g.spamh.com"]]'],
['[]'],
['"psd1-org.mail.protection.outlook.com"]]'],
['"avionte-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"]]'],
['"lastmx.spamexperts.net"]]'],
['"mx30.mailspamprotection.com"]]'],
['"grupocarval-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"]]'],
['"planttape-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"]]'],
['"alt3.aspmx.l.google.com"]]'],
['"mx30.mailspamprotection.com"]]'],
['[]'],
['"mail2.qlc.co.in"]]'],
['"mail.aherhn.org"]]'],
['"aureon-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"]]'],
['"thomascookairlines-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"]]'],
['"yourcourts-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"]]'],]

hosts_list = list(filter(bool, map(lambda x: re.findall('[\w\s.-]+', x[0]), hosts_list)))  # Чистим мусор

print(list(map(lambda x: get_fld(x[0], fix_protocol=True), hosts_list)))

# ['spamh.com', 'outlook.com', 'outlook.com', 'spamexperts.net', 'mailspamprotection.com', 'outlook.com', 'outlook.com', 'google.com', 'mailspamprotection.com', 'qlc.co.in', 'aherhn.org', 'outlook.com', 'outlook.com', 'outlook.com']
```

Comment: да это крутой пример, спасибо, только, я не понял, как добавить запятую из каждого полученного элемента в цикле, у меня идет список без запятых

Comment: Вы про разделитель между элементами списка? Если про него, то Вы вместо `for i in my_list(): print(i.split(' ')[-1:])` делаете `hosts_list = [i.split(' ')[-1:] for i in my_list()]`. Но вообще нужно просто нормально затянуть и спарсить тот текстовый файл, на который Вы картинку приложили.

Comment: круто сработало, но он не находит якобы домены, если я печатаю `print(host_list)` он выдает в результате списки списков зачищенные, например вот: ` ['mail.contactusreps.com'], ['mail.annefaucherdesigner.com'], ['alt1.aspmx.l.google.com'], ['casamodernallc-com.mail.protection.outlook.com']]` но последняя ошибка он выдает вот такую  `Domain localhost didn't match any existing TLD name!`

Comment: В `hosts_list` хранятся необработанные домены различных уровней. Дальше вместо `print(list(map(...)))` можно сделать `hosts = list(map(lambda x: get_fld(x[0], fix_protocol=True), hosts_list))`. Тогда все обработанные домены будет внутри `hosts`. И откуда localhost у Вас вылез? Посмотрите, есть ли в `hosts_list` пустые строки.

Answer (score 2):

без дополнительных библиотек

```
a = (['"remerplumbing-com.relay1g.spamh.com"]]'],
     ['[]'],
     ['"psd1-org.mail.protection.outlook.com"]]'],
     ['"avionte-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"]]'],
     ['"lastmx.spamexperts.net"]]'],
     ['"mx30.mailspamprotection.com"]]'],
     ['"grupocarval-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"]]'],
     ['"planttape-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"]]'],
     ['"alt3.aspmx.l.google.com"]]'],
     ['"mx30.mailspamprotection.com"]]'],
     ['[]'],
     ['"mail2.qlc.co.in"]]'],
     ['"mail.aherhn.org"]]'],
     ['"aureon-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"]]'],
     ['"thomascookairlines-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"]]'],
     ['"yourcourts-com.mail.protection.outlook.com"]]'])

x = []
y = []

for i in a:
    # noinspection PyBroadException
    try:
        x.append(i[0].replace(']]', '').replace('"', '').split('.')[-2])
        y.append(i[0].replace(']]', '').replace('"', '').split('.')[-1])
    except Exception:
        pass

z = ''
for a, b in zip(x, y):
    z = z + f'{a}.{b}, '

print(z[:-2])

>>> spamh.com, outlook.com, outlook.com, spamexperts.net, mailspamprotection.com, outlook.com, outlook.com, google.com, mailspamprotection.com, co.in, aherhn.org, outlook.com, outlook.com, outlook.com
```

Comment: `co.in` в данном случае домен верхнего уровня (как, к примеру, как `amazon.co.uk`)